# Is there a construct like `Either`/`Validation`?

Tags: rascal

For my use case I want to have either a successful result (with value) xor a failed result with a list of errors. 
In Haskell you could use something like `Either` for this, in Scalaz we have `Validation`. Is there a construct in Rascal for this?

Is see `Maybe` is available, I hope `Either` is as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment we only support `Maybe` in the library, but you could easily write your own `Either` if you want. Could be a useful addition to our library.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it myself for now: `data Either[&E,&A] = success(&A val) | failure(&E error);`